# Forgot Password link not working in Azure b2c using msal in angular 7 application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am able to sign up and sign in through Azure B2C but on clicking the forgot password link it is getting redirect to the home page.

```js
private app: any;
public user: any;

constructor() {
  this.app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
                   this.applicationConfig.clientID,
                   this.applicationConfig.authority,
                   (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType)=>{},          
                   { 
                     redirectUri: this.applicationConfig.redirectUrl,
                     validateAuthority:false
                   }
                 );
  // this.app.redirectUri=this.applicationConfig.redirectUrl;
}

public login() {
  let tokenData = '';
  error=>{this.redirectIfForgotPassword();}
  this.app.loginRedirect(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
          .then(data => {tokenData = data; });
}

public redirectIfForgotPassword() {
  alert("pwd");
  const errorDesc = this.appPR.errorDesc;
  if (errorDesc && errorDesc.indexOf('AADB2C90118') > -1) {
    const authUrlSplit = this.applicationConfig.authority.split('/');
    const authorityUrl = `${authUrlSplit.slice(0, authUrlSplit.length - 1).join('/')}/${this.applicationConfig.passwordResetPolicy}`;

    this.app.authority =authorityUrl;
    localStorage.setItem("app_error", this.app.error);
    //sessionStorage.remove(this.app.error);

    this.login();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

public getUser() {
  const user = this.app.getUser();
  if (user) {
      return user;
  } else {
      return null;
  }     
}

public logout() {
  this.app.logout();
}

public getToken() {
  return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
                .then(accessToken => {
                   // console.log(accessToken);       
                    return accessToken;
                }, error => {
                    return this.appPR.acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
                                    .then(accessToken => {             
                                        return accessToken;
                                    }, err => {
                                     //  console.error(err);
                                    });
                });
    }    
}
```

the Url I am getting after clicking on Forgor password link is:

> http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+228682a8-8e05-40be-b3c3-936a932fcfd2%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2019-03-12+05%3a35%3a51Z%0d%0a&state=6eff9580-1aef-43c7-89a3-d17253d4a286

The `redirectIfForgotPassword` method is not getting called.
Check if my syntax is correct.
Suggest some changes for this code.

Comment: Did you configure the reset password policy both in Azure portal and your code?

Comment: Yes I configured in both

Comment: Have you tested your b2c_reset policy on Azure portal by clicking Run user flow?https://i.stack.imgur.com/nndTd.png

Comment: the user flow is working fine

Comment: Which sample did you refer to? Can you past your code of the configuration ?

Comment: private applicationConfig: any = {
    clientID: ' ', 
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin_policy', 
    b2cScopes: ['https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/read'], 
    redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200', 
    extraQueryParameter: 'p=B2C_1_signup_signin_policy&scope=openid&nux=1' ,
    
    passwordResetPolicy:"B2C_1_passwordreset_policy",
};

Comment: @barbsan, did you get your answer?